# Is Non-breaking space (~) required for \gls commands of the glossaries(extra) package(s)?

Tags: spacing, glossaries, typography, acronyms, glossaries-extra

There is a really quick question.

Should I use a non-breaking space `~` in front of the `\gls` commands (for acronyms in my document) when using the `glossaries-extra` package?

Comment: No, not in general. `~` is usually used between text like "chapter" or "equation" and `\ref` because the cross-reference is typically just a number, but `\gls` can produce a word or phrase and there's no reason for a non-breaking space in that context.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot thank you for clarifying. Much appreciated.